# wpf toggle button : Display text along with image as content

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a toggle button ,I want to display one Image and Some Text when toggle Button Checked
and when unchecked I want to display another image and another text.

Here is my Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
<Image Source="DeActiveButton.png"
       x:Key="ImgDeactivate" />
<Image Source="ActiveButton.png"
       x:Key="ImgActivate" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
       x:Key="MyToggleButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Content"
            Value="{DynamicResource ImgDeactivate}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content"
                    Value="{DynamicResource ImgActivate}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
 <ToggleButton x:Name="btnDeactivate"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Width="85"
                          Content="Deactivate"
                          Style="{DynamicResource MyToggleButtonStyle}">
            </ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

But the Above xaml Display only Image, I want to display some text along with image depends on the toggle button state how to accomplish this

Comment: can't you put a stackpanel? something like: "<stackpanel><Image Source="DeActiveButton.png"
       x:Key="ImgDeactivate" /><<textblock text="test"/> </StackPanel>

Comment: @sexta13 But how do I change the Image and text when toggle button's state changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ContentControl`s like the `ToggleButton` can have only one `UIElement` as its content. However, this single element could quite easily be a container control, such as a `Grid` or `StackPanel`. Having set the container control as the single content element, you are then free to add as many items as you like.

If you define these controls in the `ControlTemplate` of the `ToggleButton`, then you can reference them inside the `ControlTemplate.Triggers` section. Try something like this:

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Name="Text" Text="Here's some text" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Image Name="Image" Grid.Row="1" Source="/AppName;component/Images/UncheckedImage.png" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Text" Property="Text" Value="Here's some different text" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Image" Property="Source" Value="/AppName;component/Images/CheckedImage.png" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```